# How to backup a huge mysql database in PHP with lowest usage (busy) of linux server?

Tags: php, linux, perl, mysql

We are developing a web-base application using PHP and Mysql. As you know there are limitations for backing up huge DBs using the web interface, so I need a solution to back up our huge DB by the following conditions:

1. The process can be done without web interface and must be run in command line (e.g. as a Linux service)
2. The process should use minimal usage of server resources (in the other word, while backup process is running, clients can use services on server)
3. Some features are vital (like backup, restore, compression & split backup file) and some features are optional (e.g. Mailing and FTP , ...)
4. Script must be writing in PHP or Perl.

Is there any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by huge? Can you give some absolute figures?

Comment: Have you considered AutoMySQLBackUp? http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/ It's basically scripting around mysqldump command.  "AutoMySQLBackup with a basic configuration will create Daily, Weekly and Monthly backups of one or more of your MySQL databases from one or more of your MySQL servers.

Other Features include:
- Email notification of backups
- Backup Compression and Encryption
- Configurable backup rotation
- Incremental database backups"

Answer (score 2):

Look at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for command line backup

For  complete database backup:

mysqldump -u USER_NAME -p DB_NAME > DB_NAME.sql

If your db is Huge and you don't want to take a backup of complete database. You can take backup of only single / multiple tables

mysqldump -u USER_NAME -p DB_NAME TABLE_NAME > TABLE_NAME.sql

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid scripting it at all and just use the tools that MySQL has inbuilt.  Here's a nice tutorial on mysqldump for you:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Answer (score 1):

you maybe want to consider seting up a replication to a 2nd server, and you have a live backup, if you want to store old backups you can use up the 2nd servers resources to make thous

Answer (score 0):

use nice to run the php script, with value 19 it will make the process have very low priority

```
nice -n 19 php /path/to/backupscript.php
```

Comment: that only helps if the script is CPU bound.

Comment: indeed and if the backup locks up the database doing it "nicely" will only prolong the lock.